# Regex select all before this or that

Tags: regex

I want to split my string so it will take everything before **NK-, SK-, DJ- or MU-**

```
DJXFSE DJ-13 - ABC
MUEKOP MU-27 - ABC
DJXFSE DJ-12 - ABC
NOVA KNSEAC NK-26-4 - ABC
NOVA KNSEAC NK-26-9 - ABC
SRFI KRSIXUR SK-45 ABC2
```

So the output would be

```
DJXFSE
MUEKOP 
DJXFSE 
MUEKOP 
DJXFSE 
NOVA KNSEAC
NOVA KNSEAC
SRFI KRSIXUR
```

What would be the way to choose everything before (excluding) different possibilities of characters?
I tried this

`(^.*(?=(\ DJ)|(\ MU)))`

where i thought that this part (\ DJ)|(\ MU) would mean DJ or MU, but i am obviously totally wrong.

Comment: You may just replace everything that you don't want with `\s+(?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)-.*` and replace with nothing. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AcRn5a/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*?)(?:\s+(?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C6l5tr/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)-)` - a non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)` - `DJ`, `MU`, `NK` or `SK`
  - `-` - a hyphen.

**NOTE**: If the suffixes can go missing and you need to match till end of string, you will need to add `|$` to the non-capturing group:

```sql
^(.*?)(?:\s+(?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)-|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Online regex demo is: [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nLUip/1/)

```
^.+(?= (?:DJ|MU|[NS]K)-)
```

***Explanation:***

```
^.+              ##From starting looking till everything if further mentioned look ahead is true.
(?=              ##Starting positive look ahead from here.
(?:              ##Starting a non capturing group here
  DJ|MU|[NS]K    ##Looking for either DJ OR MU OR NK OR SK here.
)                ##Closing non capturing group here.
-)               ##mentioning -(dash) and closing positive look ahead here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment adding following solution here too.

```
^(.+)( (DJ|MU|[NS]K)-)
```

Online demo for above is: [Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/nMT4LL/1/)